# How come this program waits 10 seconds instead of counting down?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++-chrono

I was trying out some c++11 code, and I tried to write a program that counts down from 10, sleeping in between the outputs. Here's what I have so far:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#include <chrono>
#include <thread>

void Sleep(int x)
{
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::duration<int>(x));
}

int main()
{
    for (int x=10; x>0; x--) {
            cout << x << "...";
            Sleep(1);
    }

    cout << " FIRE!!\n";
}
```

The problem is, this code waits 10 seconds and then prints all of the output, instead of counting down from 10. How come this is? And how can I fix it?

(By the way, I tried this on a computer running Linux Mint 17 and MacOSX 10.9, and both times I got the same result)

Comment: your cout is "cached"(no idea how to call it more correctly). call std::cout.flush() before Sleep

Comment: @Creris The usual word is "buffered".

Comment: @T.C. thanks, by brain is half asleep at the moment, so couldnt come up with that word

Comment: I/O isn't automatically flushed because that could be expensive (in terms of performance)....

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Probably because you don't flush the output. Try this

```
cout << x << "..." << flush;
```

Stream output can be buffered, which means the results don't always appear immediately. Flushing at least increases the chance that you will see some output immediately.

Comment: It works, thanks! But how come I have to flush `cout` every time?

Comment: @Dovahkiin: `iostream` (`cout` is an instance for `stdout`) and other I/O libraries are buffered. The `flush` command pushes the buffered data out before it normally goes. By default, on most platforms, `cout` flushes automatically when you print `'\n'`.

Comment: Output would be overall less efficient if every output was done immediately. Instead output is buffered and doesn't happen until a big enough chunk of data is ready to be written. Most of the time this doesn't matter but if you want to see the output immediately, then you have to use flush.

Comment: That makes sense, I guess. Thanks! +1

Comment: @Dovahkiin _"Thanks! +1"_ You should also consider accepting this answer if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You need to flush the output each time round the loop, otherwise the runtime system will wait for the buffer to be full or (sometimes) an end of line to be sent.

Also, when using `std::chrono::duration<>` it is better to use one of the explicitly defined types if possible for readability. In this case you are measuring times in *seconds* so I used `std::chrono::seconds` in your example:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#include <chrono>
#include <thread>

void Sleep(int x)
{
    // better to use explicit types for duration
    // for readability
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(x));
}

int main()
{
    for(int x = 10; x > 0; x--) {
        cout << x << "..." << std::flush; // need to flush here
        Sleep(1);
    }

    cout << " FIRE!!\n";
}
```